# CloudFront headers are not forwarded correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

We have a cloudfront configuration for our new application, which is using `Referer` header. Initially it was not configured to Forward the headers. Then we updated the CloudFront configuration to forward the header.

```
ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: 'true'
            Cookies:
              Forward: 'all'
            Headers:
              - Referer
```

But the problem is that the header is forwarded only from some clients. Is there a chance that CloudFront didn't update the settings for every user or might be using a cache. What could be done to check or resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue was not enabling `Stickie Sessions`.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have Whitelisted the Referer header in CloudFront, cached response from CloudFront will be served without the header , you need to make cache invalidation of CloudFront in order to solve this.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Answer (score 0):

Cache invalidation is the one way if that works. if the problem still persists then you can enable the CloudFront logging to log all viewer requests for your distribution and analyze them to know the root cause.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html